# How do I change Chrome homepage via command line on macosx

Tags: macos, bash, google-chrome

I try to make a pkg with a shell script which changes the homepage for Chrome on our classrooms. It's ok for Safari or Firefox, but not for Chrome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: According to the manual it's simply `--homepage`..

Comment: but i don't want to open right now a page as an homepage but rather to set homepage for standard opening of Google Chrome.

Comment: A somewhat "hacky" way is to set the homepage manually once and then copy the containing line of the config file `~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences`. Then you can adjust this line for other users.